# Spring Data JPA Fetch from one table using the relationship table

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql, many-to-one

Here is my USER entity and USER_GROUP is a relation table with GROUP.
How to fetch all Users Where groupid = ?

```
    @Entity 
    @Table(name="USER") 
    public class User implements Serializable {
      @Id Long userId;
      @ManyToOne 
      @JoinTable(name = "USER_GROUP", 
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "userid"), 
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "groupid")) 
      private List<Group> groups;
    }
```

Comment: what exactly you have tried so far? and which layer you need solution?

Comment: Are you sure your mapping is correct? Why are you having a list of `Group` when your mapping is `@ManyToOne`. `Many` Users can belong to `One` group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are using `UserRepository` as well.
In your `UserRepository` you can write a method to fetch all such data.

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{

    @Query(value="Select u from User u inner join u.groups group where group.groupid = :groupId ")
    List<User> findAllByGroupId(@Param("groupId") long groupId)

}
```

This should work. However i have not tested it.

**Note** Use `DISTINCT` to select only unique `User` objects.

Comment: is it possible without JPQL or SQL queries?